# Create sheet and update data with one request

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I want to implement Google sheets api request with one api call.

I managed to implement this code:

```
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

        List<CellData> values = new ArrayList<>();

        values.add(new CellData()
            .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
                .setStringValue("Hello World!")));

        requests.add(new Request().setAddSheet(new AddSheetRequest()
            .setProperties(new SheetProperties()
                .setTitle("scstc")))
            .setUpdateCells(new UpdateCellsRequest()
                .setStart(new GridCoordinate()
                    .setSheetId(0)
                    .setRowIndex(0)
                    .setColumnIndex(0))
                .setRows(Arrays.asList(
                    new RowData().setValues(values)))
                .setFields("userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor"))
        );

        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest body = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);

        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, body).execute();
```

But I get error:

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'updateCells'",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'updateCells'",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
    at com.google.sheet.impl.GoogleSheetBasicTest1_____1.hello(GoogleSheetBasicTest1_____1.java:133)
```

Do you how how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each `Request` object is intended to have just a single value set within it.  You are setting two values:

```
requests.add(new Request()
            .setAddSheet(...)
            .setUpdateCells(...));
```

Instead of doing the above, you need to use two request objects:

```
requests.add(new Request().setAddSheet(...));
requests.add(new Request().setUpdateCells(...));
```

Answer (score 3):

@Sam is correct, however if you are using the JSON representation make sure that your formatting is set correctly in the dictionaries you are making. I found the following formating helpfull, found in the Google Devs' Formatting cells with the Google Sheets API 
[blogpost](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/09/formatting-cells-in-google-sheets-with.html):

```
reqs = {'requests': [
    # frozen row 1, request #1
    {'updateSheetProperties': {
        'properties': {'gridProperties': {'frozenRowCount': 1}},
        'fields': 'gridProperties.frozenRowCount',
    }},
    # embolden row 1, request #2
    {'repeatCell': {
        'range': {'endRowIndex': 1},
        'cell': {'userEnteredFormat': {'textFormat': {'bold': True}}},
        'fields': 'userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold',
    }},
]}
```

*I am new to adding information to this site. Sorry if this is not he best way to add the information but I just want to help out. I had this problem while using python instead of java and found that it was a simple error of were the brackets where.

Comment: A good look would be to the relevant Google APIs Explorer website, which has an interactive JSON request builder (that also lets you send the request and examine the response)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate